# About compact region that is homeomorphic to a disk in a torus

Tags: algebraic-topology, general-topology

Let $C_1$ be a circle embedded in a standard torus $T$. Let $p$ and $q$ be two points of $C_1$. Assume that $C_2$ is a circle in $T$ distinct from $C_1$ such that $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersect at $p$ and $q$. We orient the two circles. In $C_1$, denote the arc from $p$ to $q$ by $l_1$ and from $q$ to $p$ by $l_2$. In $C_2$, denote the arc from $p$ to $q$ by $l_3$ and from $q$ to $p$ by $l_4$. We obtain three compact regions (1) region bounded by $l_1 \cup l_3$, (2) region bounded by $l_3 \cup l_2$ and (3) region bounded by $l_2 \cup l_4$. Suppose that one of the three regions above is with a hole ,i.e it is not a disk indeed. Then is it possible that one of the two remaining regions (or both of them) is (are) also not homeomorphic to a disk.

Comment: You can answer your question using euler characteristics.  Surfaces with boundary are classified by the number of boundary components + euler characteristic.  This turns your question into one of arithmetic, plus the additivity formula for Euler characteristics.  Have you tried this?

Comment: I can imagine that one of the two regions must be homeomorphic to a disk but I could not prove it. I'll try now by using Euler characteristic and return to show you my trial. Thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

I am thinking of the the following. Each of the three regions is bounded by one boundary component. If one of them is with a hole, this means that the Euler characteristic for it is given by $2-2\times 1 -1=-1$. The Euler characteristic of the torus is zero. Since the Euler characteristic is additive, the Euler characteristic of the torus is the summation of the Euler characteristic of the three regions and the region which is in the exterior of the three regions in the torus. If all the remaining regions are not disks, then the Euler characteristic is -4 which is a contradiction. Thus we obtain that if one among the three regions  is not a disk, then one among the other two must be a disk indeed. Please tell me whether my argument is true or not. Thank you

Comment: Sorry I made mistake in the answer above. The region with a hole is with Euler characteristic equal to zero since it is homeomorphic to an annulus. So no contradiction we can have that all regions are twisted. But still I am not convinced. I think one of the two remaining regions must be a disk. Do you agree with me?

Comment: Ohhh, now I understand it. It is really possible. Interesting. Ok another question: can $l_1 \cup l_2$ be hemeomorphic to a fully twisted annulus provided that the three regions in the question are with a hole. I see that the answer is no. We can find disk bounded by $l_1 \cup l_2$ and thus it must be a circle.